# LoadingFinished will be called multiple times in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

Now I have to load a webview in my project.However,the method `LoadingFinished` sometimes will be called multiple times(some url will and some not).Is it the problem of url? Such as http or https.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is an asynchronous request or redirect within the page, the above method is called multiple times. So you can refer the following code

```
[Export("webViewDidFinishLoad:")]
public void LoadingFinished(UIWebView webView)
 {
    if(webView.IsLoading==true)
     {
       return;
     }
    else
     {
       // do something you want
     }

 }
```